# Is it possible to use the WP7 Panorama or Pivot in SL4?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm making pretty heavy use of the Panorama and Pivot controls in my WP7 applications. Is it possible to use these same controls in a standard Silverlight (4) application?

http://phone.codeplex.com/

I added the dll's, was able to compile and create the controls in my views. However; I was not able to "Scroll". I thought they used the "LeftMouseDown" event handlers but I guess I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do additional work to get them to work on the desktop: manipulation events are used in phone controls since they have much more information available such as the maniupation delta.

Being an open source project I am sure they could look into adding that support, would be good to open such a work item on that site perhaps. (There are no official Pivot and Panorama controls yet from Microsoft)

Answer (score 1):

I created a panorama-like control for SL4 in the following blog post:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/10/silverlight-as-an-alternative-to-powerpoint/

It might be a good starting point for making a more fully features control